# How can I enlarge a div upon hovering over it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scaling

I have a horizontal row that contains images & I am trying to achieve the same scaling effect that netflix uses when an image is being hovered over, as shown in this video:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatever12345/net.mov

I observed that upon hovering, when the image is scaled, it sort of pushes its siblings a distance on the x-axis but then they all return to the origin position when the hover is over. I also observed that the scaled image just overlaps its container as well as elements to the top and bottom of it, rather than disturbing margins and padding. How can I recreate this action?

Here is the css & jQuery I attempted to use, but its not what I am trying to achieve:

```
.cover-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 136px;
  height: 178px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-transition: 400ms;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.cover-item-open {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 2;
}

 $('.image-container a').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('.cover-item').toggleClass('cover-item-open');
 });
```

**I've created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cm6yL10r/2/) to show my full code**

Comment: Apply the same scale on hover animation to the parent container and adjust the amount of scale of the parent as needed.

You can set the parent animation right inside the handler for the child.

Comment: this doesn't provide me with the desired effect I want. I explained in the question after the video link the desired effect. Can you help me achieve that rather? @Korgrue

Comment: In the demo mov. they have the parent div set taller than the maximum scaled height of the children. The parent div is also set to overflow: visible so it dont cut off the sides of the children when they expand. Give that a shot.

Comment: when i set the parent div to overflow:visible, while it solves the issue of overlapping other elements, eliminates the individual horizontal scroll of the row & makes the whole page scroll horizontal @Korgrue

Comment: Looks like a working solution has been provided below for you. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to do this using :hover

```
.my_div:hover {
    transform: scale(...);
}
```

EDIT: Upon further looking, this should work better

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".scalable", function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: "100px" });
    });
    $(document).on("mouseout", ".scalable", function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: "50px" });
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<img class="scalable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/22/Earth_Western_Hemisphere_transparent_background.png/600px-Earth_Western_Hemisphere_transparent_background.png" alt="earth">
<img class="scalable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/22/Earth_Western_Hemisphere_transparent_background.png/600px-Earth_Western_Hemisphere_transparent_background.png" alt="earth">
```

The same basic idea should work for divs, just images are easier to see.

Comment: this doesn't provide me with the desired effect I want. I explained in the question after the video link the desired effect. Can you help me achieve that rather?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think it better fits what you were originally asking. You should be able to expand the css in animate to do fancier things